# Expresiones regulares para contraseña en base a una politica

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de validar la contraseña utilizando expresiones regulares. La contraseña debe de seguir las siguientes politicas:

- Minimo 8 caracteres
- Maximo 15
- Al menos una letra mayúscula
- Al menos una letra minucula
- Al menos un dígito
- No espacios en blanco
- Al menos 1 caracter especial

Estoy usando esta expresion que si funciona, pero el problema es que me admite espacios en blanco:

```
regexp_password = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}/;
```

Comment: En particular, este tipo de validaciones las prefiero hacer en un método en lugar de un solo regexp con el poder de dios. Podrías facilitarte el trabajo utilizando un regexp que sea una primera validación, luego una función que termine de afinar los detalles de tu política.

Comment: nota al margen, no hay por que poner limites en el largo de la contraseña ni evitar que se utilizen espacios es blanco. Revisa esto http://www.passworddragon.com/password-vs-passphrase (en ingles)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
var regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ]){8,15}$/;
```

[image: regex]

Comment: Esta funciona bien

Comment: Funcionó perfecto

Comment: Faltaria agregar mas caracteres especiales, quedaría así:   /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&#.$($)$-$_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&#.$($)$-$_]{8,15}$/;

Comment: Hola, pudieras decirme con que software has creado la imagen?

Answer (score 4):

El problema está en que esta parte de la regexp

```
[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}
```

se satisface con 8 caracteres del conjunto. O sea, después del octavo caracter, tu regexp permite cualquier cosa.

Lo que hay que hacer es acotarla al final, para que solo acepte strings en los que, después de los 8 a 15 caracteres del conjunto de caracteres permitidos, termine el string.

TL;DR: hay que agregar `$` al final.

> `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}$/`
>
> ```
>                                                                     acá ^
> ```

Comment: Funciono perfecto

Answer (score 2):

Después de varios intentos no lo pude lograr, ya que como comentan, no es muy seguro este método. Así que lo que hice es una validación antes para detectar si tiene algún espacio en blanco

```
if(/\s/.test($scope.Password)){
    $scope.isValidPassword = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Siempre es lo mejor ;)

Answer (score 1):

Puede validar tu regex, y efectivamente algunos casos con espacios en blanco son validos.

Considero que podrías quitarlos antes de tu input, y después validar con tu regex.

Puedes usar `.replace(/ /g,'')` para remover los espacios en blanco

Aqui un pequeño [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc25r1h6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Habría que negar el espacio en blanco con `[^'\s]` por lo que la expreción completa quedaría asi:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}[^'\s]/
```

Pruébala [aqui](http://regexper.com/)

Comment: Hay algunos casos que si admite el espacio en blanco `ASFFAFD5a8ad$ a`

Comment: Es verdad! por que está puesta al final y habría que ponerlas en distintos puntos para que funcione... la verdad no es buena solución.  Me parece más óptima la que indicas tu.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta parte:

```
([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ])
```

deberia ser así:

```
(^[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]+$)
```

y de esta manera evalúa en toda la expresión desde el principio hasta el final y no hace falta negar el espacio en blanco, ya quw solo aceptaría los caracteres que le estas diciendo.

Comment: Hola!! gracias por la respuesta!! tene en cuenta que la pregunta tiene mas de 2 años, y puede que no tengas ninguna clase de feedback al respecto, y mas que tiene otras 4 respuestas! como referencia, podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Gracias por aportar!

Comment: Hola como estas? si me di cuenta q era un post viejo, pasa q lo resolvi y necesitaba contarselo a alguien jeje. Saludos